# SQL query is not returning the correct answer

Tags: sql

I have table with 3 columns:

```
name char, depr int, grade int
```

I have these values:

```
A  1  10  
A  2  12  
B  1  -5  
B  2   8  
C  1  -5  
C  2 -15  
C  3  30
```

I want found if somebody have negative grade, what it's sum of grade

My query :

```
select  
    T1.name,  
    sum(T1.grade)  
from
    Table_1 T1 
join 
    Table_1 T2 on T1.name = T2.name   
               and T2.grade < 0  
group by 
    T1.name
```

This query returns an incorrect answer for value C: it returns 20, but the correct answer is 10.

Name B returns the correct answer.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: (-5) + (-15) = -20

Comment: I try it SQL Server and in Oracle . query wery simple . Rigth answer need to be C =     ( -5) + (-15) + 30 = 10 . by query I have C = 20

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7549966a11d8af0cc144e4e640ed393b)

Comment: If you want to select the `name` of those who have a `SUM(grade) OVER(PARTITION BY name)`, this won't be a good example dataset because none of them has a negative sum of grades. Or do you want the sum of grades of names that have at least one negative grade? In the latter case, the answer by @GordonLinoff is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

> I want found if somebody have negative grade,

You can use aggregation with filtering:

```
select name, sum(grade)
from table1
group by name
having min(grade) < 0;
```

You are getting the wrong answer because you are using a self-join which multiplies the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT T1.name,  
        sum(T1.grade)  
from Table_1 T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table_1 T2 
                 WHERE T1.name = T2.name   
                   and T2.grade < 0  )
group by T1.name;
```